# Bypass routes with exactly 2 parameters in Loopback

Tags: express, routes, loopbackjs, loopback

One of my Loopback routes inside *boot/routes.js* is:

```
router.get('/:foo?/:bar?', function(req, res, next) {
  ...
})
```

And now GET `/api/user` no longer works because it is catched by this route.

**How do I bypass this route (when I want to fetch the API) in Loopback?**

**Is there a built-in method/middleware to do that or should I use `next()`?**

Comment: what about use remote methods for the problem ?

Comment: @ChamalPradeep What do you mean exactly? You mean to extend the model.js? I would like to separate views logic and data logic. The GET route currently shows a view.

Comment: use remoteMethod that is best for this avaoid using direct routes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a route directly on the express router. The loopback framework exposes functionality to create ["remote methods"](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-methods.html) on your models. Assuming that you're using a PersistedModel as your base, I would recommend using query parameters for your arguments, instead of plopping them in the path. That way, you won't override any of the built-in model methods.

In `/common/models/user.js`:

```
User.foobar = function(foo, bar, cb) {
 // TODO: implementation
}
User.remoteMethod('foobar',{
  accepts: [
    {arg: 'foo', type: 'string'},
    {arg: 'bar', type: 'string'}
  ],
  returns: {arg: 'baz', type: 'string'},
  http: {verb: 'get'}
});
```